# Logo missing on mobile bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

under 768px my .navbar logo goes missing. I saw another post with this issue, but they had a really high height set. I don't have a height set for my navbar or navbar brand. Really appreciate any help, thanks.

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
}

.navbar>.container,
.navbar>.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark" style="background-image: url(http://go.pardot.com/l/679853/2019-01-07/2cz/679853/633/events_hero_1_smaller.png); background-position: top left; background-size: 100%; background-repeat: repeat;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar19">
      <span class="navbar-brand d-md-block">
          <img src="https://www.merceradvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Mercer_Advisors_Logo_white.svg" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="navbar-text text-light w-50 mr-auto" style="">
  <img src="https://jq92i2jx71t1ha9ez393dz6k-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Kristen.png" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top rounded-circle mr-2" alt="" style="border: 2px solid #49dbc3 ; border-color: #49dbc3;  ">
   <span>
     <b class="" style="vertical-align: middle align-items:center; line-height:30px;">
        <a href="tel:888.565.1681">CALL US NOW: 888.565.1681</a>
     </b>
   </span>
  </span>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your issue, I can see the logo fine on small screens

Comment: Have you used dev tools to inspect your dom, it should give you an indication on what is causing the image to not be visible. It's hard to tell with the info provided.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after tweaking a little, I see that you're not including Bootstrap on you snippet, so people will not be able to see the issue with the code provided.

Now after adding Bootstrap, I see you have the logo *inside* the `navbar-collapse` container, this is what gets hidden once you reach a breakpoint, so it can be expanded with a button. You can either take the logo out of this box, or simply tell the `navbar` to always expand, by setting the class `navbar-expand` without any breakpoint.

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
}

.navbar>.container,
.navbar>.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-dark navbar-dark" style="background-image: url(http://go.pardot.com/l/679853/2019-01-07/2cz/679853/633/events_hero_1_smaller.png); background-position: top left; background-size: 100%; background-repeat: repeat;">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="navbar-brand d-md-block">
          <img src="https://www.merceradvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Mercer_Advisors_Logo_white.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
      </span>
  </div>
  <span class="navbar-text text-light w-50 mr-auto" style="">
  <img src="https://jq92i2jx71t1ha9ez393dz6k-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Kristen.png" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top rounded-circle mr-2" alt="" style="border: 2px solid #49dbc3 ; border-color: #49dbc3;  ">
   <span>
     <b class="" style="vertical-align: middle align-items:center; line-height:30px;">
        <a href="tel:888.565.1681">CALL US NOW: 888.565.1681</a>
     </b>
   </span>
  </span>
</nav>
```